# I Cant Use Facebook Graph of My Public Page Without Auth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get page details of my page via this graph request: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/Insan.Kaynaklari.Turkiye

But always returns:

```
{
error: {
message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
type: "OAuthException",
code: 104
}
}
```

My page has no any restriction:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are very few facebook api calls that don't require an oauth access token. You can read about them here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Moreover, even accessing your own information will require you to register an application with Facebook so that you can get the credentials needed to do the oauth authentication.

This is something that most programming languages/frameworks have libraries for. It's usually a matter of dropping some pre-existing code into your application/project.